# Can you bind a variable to an id or class using Input()

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In Angular 9 is there a way to bind a variable to a class or id? I want to pass unique ids or classes from a parent component to the child and I tried using Input() but the class/id just displays the actual variable name that I assign to it.

For example:

Child Component
HTML File

```
<div id="uniqueId"></div
```

Typescript

```
@Input() uniqueId: string;
```

Parent Component
HTML

```
<child-comp *ngFor="let data of dataArray let i=index" [uniqueId]="id-{{i}}">
```

Comment: Please provide some more concrete code sample to clarify what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: updated question with example

Answer (score 1):

1. In the child component, use property binding for the `id` property:

```html
<div [id]="uniqueId"></div>
```

2. In the parent component, use the following property binding syntax:

```html
<child-comp *ngFor="let data of dataArray; let i = index" [uniqueId]="'id-' + i">
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3gcja7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild-section.component.ts) for a demo.